# Bloom Filter of MongoDB ids in Redis and Go

Tags: go, redis, bloom-filter

I'm working on articles suggestions. There are lots of them. Think about YouTube videos suggestions. To avoid suggesting article once again I'd like to remember which were seen already by particular user. I have lot's of users and I'd like to avoid infinitely growing database of history as well.

Every article has [MongoDB ObjectId](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/org/bson/types/ObjectId.html). I use Redis and Go language.

I think that Bloom Filter could solve this problem, because false positives are ok in this case. I'd like to avoid false negatives, but it's not 100% obligatory.

I don't know any sensible alternative to Bloom Filter in this area. Should I?

I can't find any implementation of Bloom Filter for Redis in Go. Can somebody advice me is it the best choice, how can I write my own or is there any existing implementation?

Comment: For bloom filters: [http://godoc.org/?q=bloom](http://godoc.org/?q=bloom). You would probably have to provide the "glue" between Redis and the filters, unless you find something specific.

Comment: I believe you'll want to use http://redis.io/commands/setbit and http://redis.io/commands/getbit to implement your bloom filter.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone stumbling across this post, if you're using Redis in this situation, then you probably want to use its [HyperLogLog feature](http://redis.io/commands/pfadd); Antirez wrote about it at length [here](http://antirez.com/news/75).  No need to figure out how to make a bloom filter in Redis, it has something just as good built in (and it can also tell you approximately how many items have been inserted in it).

Comment: Redis doesn't provide a command for querying whether an item has been inserted into a hyperloglog or not, and for good reason — hyperloglogs aren't very good for doing that at all! They have much less accuracy for the same space than Bloom filters do. Hyperloglogs are good for "count distinct", but that's not what this question is about.

Comment: @hobbs, feel free to correct me if I'm wrong, but couldn't the result of the `PFADD` command be used to tell if a particular item (in this case the youtube video) has been placed in the hyperloglog? The return value indicates if the approximate cardinality changed after executing the command.  If the cardinality didn't change, it's safe to assume the item has already been added to the set.

Comment: 1. that doesn't allow probing without adding.
2. hyperloglog isn't designed for that kind of technique. You're correct that adding an already-added item won't change the state of the HLL, but adding a new item *also* usually doesn't change the state (the probability goes down as the number of items added goes up).

If you used a temporary copy to deal with point #1, I see how you *could* use it that way, but I think the false-positive performance would be very bad because of point #2. Bloom filters are better.

Comment: In the 2 years since this was posted, it looks like Redis now has support for this via [modules](https://redislabs.com/blog/rebloom-bloom-filter-datatype-redis/).

Answer (score 0):

As @jumand mentioned, Redis has a module named RedisBloom which provides a Bloom Filter, Cuckoo Filter, Count-Min Sketch and TopK services.

http://redisbloom.io